# Problem with hhline with tables having more than 9 columns

Tags: tables, rules

I found out that the hhline does not print lines when the argument is greater than `9` as in `\hhline{|*14{-}|}`. It works well when doing instead `\hhline{|*9{-}*5{-}|}` as the following file shows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hhline{|*9{-}|}
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} & & \multicolumn{7}{c|}{Year} \\ \hhline{|*9{-}|}
a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a \\ \hhline{|*9{-}|}
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hhline{|*9{-}*5{-}|}
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} & & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{Year} \\ \hhline{|*9{-}*5{-}|}
a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a \\ \hhline{|*9{-}*5{-}|}
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hhline{|*14{-}|}
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} & & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{Year} \\ \hhline{|*14{-}|}
a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a \\ \hhline{|*14{-}|}
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Is this the expected behavior ?

Answer (score 4):

The expected thing is to put the number in `{...}` as in `\hhline{|*{14}{-}|}`. If you do only `\hhline{|*14{-}|}`, LaTeX actually thinks that you want to replicate `1` time the string `4`, and not `14` times the string `-`.

The fact that it works correctly on one-digit numbers is a bit misfortunate since people then think it's the correct syntax; but it is not.

As a side note, please do not use `\sf`, use `\sffamily` instead. Reasons are explained in the question: [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)